# Error with IIF statement in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014, iif

I am creating an SQL Server 2014 view in Management Studio which uses the IIF statement but I keep getting the error: An expression on non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected.

I tried a new view with a super-simple IIF statement and it too failed.

This is the statement I am using to test: SELECT IIF('1=1', 'True', 'False') AS Expr1

Comment: remove the single quotes in `'1=1'`, it should be just `1=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT IIF(1=1, 'True', 'False') AS Expr1
```

`'1=1'` you had previously was not a `boolean` condition. Changed it to `1=1`

Comment: I did type it in as 1=1 but Management Studio changes it to '1=1'

Comment: i haven't seen Management Studio behaving the way you say.

Comment: Management studio changed it on its own?, **how** are you writing your code?

Comment: Management Studio has a visual tool for creating views that has multiple panes. I was writing the IIF statement in the "Criteria" pane that has columns called Column, Alias, Table, etc.  In that pane, the boolean condition inside the IIF statement will get opening and closing single quotes added automatically! However, if I write the IIF statement directly in the SQL pane then it works. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

What it means is that the first parameter must return a true or false condition. Therefore, evaluating two integers will produce that. What you currently had was just a string

```
SELECT IIF(1=1, 'True', 'False') AS Expr1
```

Can do '1' = '1' as well